# There's no [about] link at the top

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface

[image: no about.]

The site exists at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/about, but there's no link to it.

Comment: It's not a bug. The link is only there if your rep is low (ie. you're a new user), since only a limited number of links are allowed to take up valuable screen real estate up there

Comment: @PrivatePansy "low" seems to be relative, my 2.2k SO account is still shown that link. And it's not that big a link actually...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all users get the link.

Users with enough reputation (specifically the [approve tag wiki edits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege threshold) are assumed to be those who already know how to use the site...

Comment: Huh, I have the `about` on most sites - this seems to be connected to rep actually: On SO (where the about link is present) I have ~2.2k, on Arqade ~6k (where it is not)

Comment: @Zommuter - You are correct. Updating answer.

Comment: That's quite high given that `about` explains _very_ basic stuff. Then again I would otherwise never have gotten my badge for reading it...